# How can I get to the level of understanding Paul Dirac's book The Principles of Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education

I'm 16 and have been trying to understand QM for about a year now. How can I improve myself to get to the level of understanding Paul Dirac's book?

Comment: Dirac's book is a classic but is not a good place to start for a beginner because it is so concise. Quantum Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum by Leonard Susskind and Art Friedman is a better text for beginners.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a helpful answer.